# Okhttp websocket Expected HTTP 101 response but was '400 ' with spring boot server

Tags: android, spring-boot, websocket, okhttp

I am developing an Android application with a Spring Boot server.

So, I open a WebSocket connection with OkHttp from my Android application to the Spring Boot server that uses Stomp.

When the WebSocket connection is closed for some exception thrown in the server and I try to reconnect, I get `Expected HTTP 101 response but was '400 '` error.

For testing purposes, I throw an exception when the Android application sends SEND frame to Server.

So this test goes like this

1. Send WebSocket Upgrade request
2. Once WebSocket connection is open, send CONNECT Stomp request
3. Then, send SUBSCRIBE Stomp request to subscribe to a queue
4. Then, send a message in SEND Stomp Frame, then the server throws an exception
5. The server will respond ERROR Stomp frame and closes the WebSocket connection.
6. I try to reconnect by going through step 1-3

Here is the code for testing.

When I first launch my Android application, it sends WebSocket request to the server as follows. I made up the IP address but in my real application, I use the correct one.

```
val webSocketRequest = Request.Builder().url("199.166.1.100:8081/websocket").build()
socket = okHttpClient.newWebSocket(webSocketRequest, this)
```

The WebSocket request looks like this

```
Request{method=GET, url=http://199.166.1.100:8081/websocket, tags={}}
```

Then, the server sends following response and onOpen() function is called, which means handshake worked fine.

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=101, message=, url=http://199.166.1.100:8081/websocket}
```

In onOpen() function, I send a Stomp CONNECT request to the server and the server responds CONNECTED and then I send SUBSCRIBE request to a queue. So far, everything works fine.

I have added an Interceptor to StompMessageBorker to throw an exception for SEND request as follows

```
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, @NonNull MessageChannel channel) {
        StompHeaderAccessor stompHeaderAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
        StompCommand stompCommand = stompHeaderAccessor.getCommand();
        
        if (StompCommand.SEND.equals(stompCommand))
            throw new RuntimeException();

        return message;
    }
```

So, I send a message in SEND Stomp frame and when the `RuntimeException` is thrown, the server sends an ERROR Stomp Frame or response to the Android application, and the onClosing() and onClosed() functions of OkHttp Websocket are called, which means that the WebSocket connection is closed.

Here is the problem, after the WebSocket connection is closed, I try to reconnect the WebSocket with following function and basically goes through the same process, send CONNECT request, then SUBSCRIBE request.

```
override suspend fun reconnect() {
    socket?.close(1000, null)
    val webSocketRequest = Request.Builder().url("199.166.1.100:8081/websocket").build()
    socket = okHttpClient.newWebSocket(webSocketRequest, this)
    
}
```

but I get `Expected HTTP 101 response but was '400 '` and even onOpen() function is not called, I guess there is some issue with a handshake.

A couple of things I noticed by carrying out this test.

1. The first three or four reconnection requests worked as expected, the onOpen() function was called, I could subscribe to the queue as well. But after 3 or 4 times, I start getting this error `Expected HTTP 101 response but was '400 '`, since then, every reconnection request got the same error.
2. Once I get this `Expected HTTP 101 response but was '400 '`, Rebooting my Spring Boot server does not help, but If re-launch my Android application, then I can connect the Websocket. But I end up getting the same error after 3 or 4 disconnections triggered by sending a message which throws an exception.

Do you guys have any idea of this issue? or Am I doing the wrong thing?

How could I establish the WebSocket connection even after 3 or 4 times of disconnection?

Thanks in advance.

=============== UPDATE =================================

I have added a `HandshakeInterceptor` to see if there is an issue in `beforeHandshake()`.

Obviously, when I get the 101 reponse, the `beforeHandshake()` is called.

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=101, message=, url=http://199.166.1.100:8081/websocket}
```

However, when I get 400 response

```
Expected HTTP 101 response but was '400 '
```

The `beforeHandshake()` is not called at all. How come `beforeHandshake()` is not even called, because I send a handshake request to the server from Android?

=============== UPDATE =================================

Let me just get things easier.

I did following tests

1. Run the Spring Boot server
2. Launch Android application.
3. WebSocket connection is successfully made.
4. Reboot the Spring Boot server
5. WebSocket connection is closed
6. Android sends HTTP handshake to reconnect the WebSocket and I got `Expected HTTP 101 response but was '400 '`

I am not sure why rebooting makes the server behave differently.

Comment: did u get this solved?

Comment: @Mr.Jay Hello there, I did not get this solved as I was quite busy with work, do you have an idea?

Comment: @KisungTae did you get this solved now?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the WebSocket URL to `ws://10.0.2.2:8080/<your_end_point_here>/websocket` works for me.
You must add `/websocket` after your end point.

Comment: Can you add a reference? (official documentation or otherwise)